# Copy files from one folder to another remotely in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy files from one folder on `F:` to `H:` on a remote machine. I write the following script but not working, tried with list down all the files, but am getting following error:

> Create-Credentials : The term 'Create-Credentials' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check

For example:

My remote server is 143.56.23.99
User name : jyoti
Password: Test123#
Source File: F:\SourceFolder\
Destination : H:\Destination\

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Computer,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Destination,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $Password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [PSCredential] $Credential
)

if($UserName -and $Password) {
    $Credential = Create-Credentials -Username $Username -Password $Password
} elseif(-not ($Credential)) {
    throw("Unable to authenticate. A username and password or pscredentials must be provided.")
}

$Items = (Get-ChildItem $Path).FullName
$NetworkLocation = Join-Path -Path "\\$Computer" -ChildPath ($Destination.Replace(':', '$'))

foreach ($Item in $Items) {
    Write-Host "------------>$Item"
}
```

Comment: Why Powershell? [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is made for.

Comment: @Olaf I want to automate it through any CI tool.

Comment: 'Create-Credentials' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. You cant invent cmdlets and expect it to work,

Comment: Use this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/. Either way, i do not see any code that copy files. Refer: Copy-Item : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6

Comment: by `Create-Credentials` do you mean `get-credentials` ?

Comment: @RohinSidharth yeah, I am just listing out the files now, copying operation will be simple for me after this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up on [using Credentials](http://duffney.io/AddCredentialsToPowerShellFunctions) as it will help you understand what's going on with your code.

---

`Create-Credentials` is not a native powershell cmdlet, either go back to where you got your code from and get that function too.

Or remove the function and use native powershell code.

Replace:

```
$Credential = Create-Credentials -Username $Username -Password $Password
```

with:

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: I am getting "Unable to authenticate. A username and password or pscredentials must be provided." error

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK How did you invoke the function? You must either provide username *and* password, or a PSCredential object.

Comment: [143.56.23.99] Connecting to remote server 143.56.23.99 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. 
Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, 
most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm 
quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers after few modification to the script I am getting the above error, I checked the remote machine 
`PS C:\Users\jmallick> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.`